# How can Current_user filter other users based on same category as the current_user belongs to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, average, chartkick

I'm building an RailsApp were the User can declare their `:buisness_type` via `f.select`in the `views/profiles/_form.html.erb`.

And then in the `views/users/show.html.erb` the `current_user` can enter values for car travels in an input_field.

What I want to be able to do is to let the current_user filter out other users based on their :buisness_type. So the current_user can see in the `views/users/show.html.erb` the Average for other users car_trip in the same `:business_type`.

In the `views/profiles/_form.html.erb` I have this code which get saved in the `Profile.rb`model:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :buisness_type %>               
         <%= f.select(:buisness_type, grouped_options_for_select(Profile::BUISNESS_TYPES),{ :class => 'form-control' })%>
</div>
```

And in the `views/users/show.html.erb` I´m rendering this partial:

```
<%= form_for @transport, html: {class: 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>

    <div class="control-group"> 
        <%= f.label :Transport_type, class: 'control-label' %><br>
        <div class="controls">
            <%= f.select(:transport_type, options_for_select(Transport::TRANSPORT_TYPES)) %>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="control-group"> 
        <%= f.label :Trip_length_km, class: 'control-label' %><br>
            <div class="controls">
                <%= f.number_field :transport_km %>
            </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="control-group"> 
        <%= f.label :Number_of_trips, class: 'control-label' %><br>
            <div class="controls">
                <%= f.number_field :transport_num_of_trips %>
            </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="control-group"> 
        <%= f.label :Recycled_fuel, class: 'control-label' %><br>
            <div class="controls">
                <%= f.number_field :transport_km_recycled_fuel %>
            </div>
    </div>  


    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
      <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-xs btn-warning' %>
        </div>  
    </div>


 <% end %>  

    <%= link_to 'Back', transports_path %>

</div>
```

I´m also rendering this column Chart in the `views/users/show.html.erb` This is a Chartkicks Chart.

```
    <div class="col-md-6 chart-box">

                     <%= column_chart [
              {name: "CarTrips #{current_user.profile.name}", data: current_user.transports.group(:transport_type).sum(:transport_km)},
              {name: "CarTrips Everyone Median", data: Transport.group(:transport_type).average(:transport_km)}], { stacked: true, height: "300px", xtitle: "CarTrips", ytitle: "Km/CarTrips"} %>

        </div>
```

As you can see I'm able to show the average car trip for Every User no matter in what kind of business they are in.  How can I let the Current_user only see the Average for Car trips of other users in the same business type they are in??? Is that even possible.

In the `users_controller.rb` I've this in the `show`method

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = User.order('created_at DESC').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30)
    @transport = current_user.transports.build
end
```

**ADDED Models**

this is the `user.rb` model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

  def average_transport_types
    self.transports.group(:transport_type).sum(:transport_km) 
  end
end
```

this is the `profile.rb`model

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `where` onto the part that pulls out the users eg:

```
@users = User.where(:business_type => current_user.business_type).order('created_at DESC').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30)
```

Comment: Thanks, I get it, but it gives me this error `undefined method 'business_type' for #<User:0x007f804a7b9c70>`

Comment: Can't I just do it like this`@bus_type = User.where(:buisness_type => current_user.profile.buisness_type).order('created_at DESC').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30)` but I'm not sure how to integrate the `@bus_type` to the Column_Chart

Comment: sure, though I wouldn't call is `@bus_type` - that name doesn't reflect what you are doing... which is pulling out a new set of users, filtered by business-type. I'd be inclined to call it something like `@users_by_business_type` or similar... be explicit with your naming to be kind to your future self reading back over this stuff :)

Comment: I have no idea how to integrate it into your column_chart - I suspect that's a different question. You use this new, filtered set of users exactly how you'd have used the original set of users... ie make a chart on its own, or iterate through it to make your own table... or read up on the doco for your charting gem to find out how to integrate two sets of data.